# Safe and most efficient way to get the column number of sliced pandas dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a function with an argument that can accept a pandas dataframe or some columns of a dataframe. When I pass a single column the shape is e.g. df.shape=(10,) and therefore trying to get the number of columns with df.shape[1] throws an error.

I found a solution by using a ternary statement, but is there a more concise and efficient way to get the number of columns in both cases (when the argument is a dataframe with more than 1 column or a series/one column from a sliced dataframe?).

```
import pandas as pd
def number_of_cols(input):
    return input.shape[1]
df=pd.DataFrame()
number_of_cols(df)
0   #good
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,2],'B':['a','b','c']})
number_of_cols(df)
2   #good
number_of_cols(df['A'].shape[1]) #Throws an error

def number_of_cols(input):
    return 1 if len(input.shape) == 1 else input.shape[1]
number_of_cols(df['A'].shape[1])
1   #good, but is there anything more concise?
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
def number_of_cols(input):
    try:
        return input.shape[1]
    except IndexError:
        return 1
```

Usage:

```
In [63]: number_of_cols(df['A'])
Out[63]: 1

In [64]: number_of_cols(df)
Out[64]: 2
```